# Is it possible to create counts by date on historic events table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an events table which contains the date of status changes. What I'm trying to achieve is to produce summary counts for each date, however I'm struggling as it is not a straight count by date but instead a count based on the last time the status changed.

The data is as follows:

```
------------------------------------------
IT_ID   NEW_STATUS  OLD_STATUS  TIMESTAMP
------------------------------------------
100     4           3           06/05/2019
100     3           2           04/05/2019
200     2           1           03/05/2019
100     2           1           02/05/2019
300     2           1           02/05/2019
200     1           -           01/05/2019
100     1           -           01/05/2019
300     1           -           01/05/2019
-------------------------------------------
```

I've tried grouping, but this hasn't worked due to the above, SQL below for the straight count.

```
select max(trunc(timestamp)), new_status ,count(new_status)
from status_hist
where trunc(timestamp) >= '01/01/2019'
group by trunc(timestamp), new_status
```

Ideally I would like the data in the following format, however the key here is to counts against each date. Note, as no status changes took place on the 05/05/19 then it shows the same of the 04/05/19:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Date        Status 1    Status 2    Status 3    Status 4
---------------------------------------------------------
06/05/2019  0           2           0           1
05/05/2019  0           2           1           0
04/05/2019  0           2           1           0
03/05/2019  0           3           0           0
02/05/2019  1           2           0           0
01/05/2019  3           0           0           0
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think about handling this problem by getting the status of each person on each date.  That requires a `cross join` to get the person/dates combinations and then some aggregation:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT min_dt + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
      FROM (SELECT MIN(ts) AS min_dt, MAX(ts) AS max_dt
            FROM   test_data 
           )
      CONNECT BY min_dt + LEVEL - 1 <= max_dt
     )
SELECT d.dt, i.it_id, max(td.new_status) keep (dense_rank first order by td.ts desc) as status
FROM dates d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT IT_ID FROM test_data) i LEFT JOIN
     test_data td
     ON td.IT_ID = i.IT_ID AND td.ts <= d.dt
GROUP BY d.dt, i.it_id;
```

The `dates` CTE is just calculating all dates.  The rest is bringing in the latest status.

This can then be expanded to aggregate (or pivot) the results:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT min_dt + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
      FROM (SELECT MIN(ts) AS min_dt, MAX(ts) AS max_dt
            FROM   test_data 
           )
      CONNECT BY min_dt + LEVEL - 1 <= max_dt
     ),
     di as (
      SELECT d.dt, i.it_id, max(td.new_status) keep (dense_rank first order by td.ts desc) as status
      FROM dates d CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT DISTINCT IT_ID FROM test_data) i LEFT JOIN
           test_data td
           ON td.IT_ID = i.IT_ID AND td.ts <= d.dt
      GROUP BY d.dt, i.it_id
     )
select dt,
       sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_1,
       sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as num_2,
       sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as num_3,
       sum(case when status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as num_4
from di
group by dt
order by dt desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d7da4f17ee4009272c9f481d6962a6b3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this provided exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using windowed aggregation functions:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( IT_ID, NEW_STATUS, OLD_STATUS, "TIMESTAMP" ) AS
SELECT 100, 4, 3,    DATE '2019-05-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 3, 2,    DATE '2019-05-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 2, 1,    DATE '2019-05-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 2, 1,    DATE '2019-05-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 2, 1,    DATE '2019-05-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 1, NULL, DATE '2019-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 1, NULL, DATE '2019-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 1, NULL, DATE '2019-05-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       dt AS "TIMESTAMP",
       COUNT( CASE new_status WHEN 1 THEN IT_ID END ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
         - COUNT( CASE old_status WHEN 1 THEN IT_ID END ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
         AS Status1,
       COUNT( CASE new_status WHEN 2 THEN IT_ID END ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
         - COUNT( CASE old_status WHEN 2 THEN IT_ID END ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
         AS Status2,
       COUNT( CASE new_status WHEN 3 THEN IT_ID END ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
         - COUNT( CASE old_status WHEN 3 THEN IT_ID END ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
         AS Status3,
       COUNT( CASE new_status WHEN 4 THEN IT_ID END ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
         - COUNT( CASE old_status WHEN 4 THEN IT_ID END ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
         AS Status4
FROM   test_data t
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT min_dt + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
         FROM   ( SELECT MIN("TIMESTAMP") AS min_dt,
                         MAX("TIMESTAMP") AS max_dt
                  FROM   test_data 
                )
         CONNECT BY min_dt + LEVEL - 1 <= max_dt
       ) c
       ON ( c.dt = t."TIMESTAMP" )
ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP" DESC
```

**Output**:

```
TIMESTAMP | STATUS1 | STATUS2 | STATUS3 | STATUS4
:-------- | ------: | ------: | ------: | ------:
06-MAY-19 |       0 |       2 |       0 |       1
05-MAY-19 |       0 |       2 |       1 |       0
04-MAY-19 |       0 |       2 |       1 |       0
03-MAY-19 |       0 |       3 |       0 |       0
02-MAY-19 |       1 |       2 |       0 |       0
01-MAY-19 |       3 |       0 |       0 |       0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3d14b9e5238dd5d2307855843e610882)*

Answer (score -1):

You can use the pivot function of SQL.
I don't have an oracle DB to test this:

```
declare @dates table(Date timestamp(3), NEW_STATUS number(10))

 v_StartDate DATE := (SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM [test].dbo)
 v_EndDate DATE := (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM [test].dbo)

insert into @dates 
SELECT  nbr * INTERVAL '1' DAY(5) - 1 + v_StartDate as 'Date', null as NEW_STATUS
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
FROM      sys.columns c
) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= v_EndDate - v_StartDate


SELECT timestamp as 'Date', 1 AS 'Status 1', 2 AS 'Status 2', 3 AS 'Status 3', 4 AS 'Status 4'  
FROM   
(SELECT Date as 'timestamp', NVL(NVL(d.new_status, t.NEW_STATUS),t2.NEW_STATUS) as new_status
FROM @dates d
left outer join Table_test t on d.Date = t.TIMESTAMP
left outer join Table_test t2 on INTERVAL '-1' DAY(5) +d.Date = t2.TIMESTAMP and NVL(d.new_status, t.NEW_STATUS) is null ) p  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT (new_status)  
FOR new_status IN  
( 1, 2, 3, 4 )  
) AS pvt  
ORDER BY pvt.TIMESTAMP desc
```

My Microsoft SQL Syntax is:

```
declare @dates table([Date] datetime, [NEW_STATUS] int)

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = (SELECT MIN(timestamp) FROM [test].[dbo].[Table_test])
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM [test].[dbo].[Table_test])

insert into @dates 
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate) as 'Date', null as NEW_STATUS
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
FROM      sys.columns c
) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)


SELECT timestamp as 'Date', [1] AS 'Status 1', [2] AS 'Status 2', [3] AS 'Status 3', [4] AS 'Status 4'  
FROM   
(SELECT Date as 'timestamp', ISNULL(ISNULL(d.new_status, t.NEW_STATUS),t2.NEW_STATUS) as new_status
FROM @dates d
left outer join Table_test t on d.Date = t.TIMESTAMP
left outer join Table_test t2 on DATEADD(DAY,-1,d.Date) = t2.TIMESTAMP and ISNULL(d.new_status, t.NEW_STATUS) is null ) p  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT (new_status)  
FOR new_status IN  
( [1], [2], [3], [4] )  
) AS pvt  
ORDER BY pvt.TIMESTAMP desc
```